# Set current date based on selection form ComboBox using WPF and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to figure out a way to get the current date and set that value to "Completed On" only when Status is set to "Inactive if Status is set to "Active" then i want Completed On to be empty. I was think this could be accomplished by using a trigger event. I am also writing this app in MVVM format.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dgRad" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
   <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Completed On"
                                  Width="Auto"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding EndDate, Mode=OneWay}" />

      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Status" 
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Status, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" 
                                  IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True">

                 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <ComboBoxItem>Active</ComboBoxItem>
                                        <ComboBoxItem>Inactive</ComboBoxItem>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                 </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>

</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is logic that you want at your view model level, not in the XAML.

Depending on what sort of framework you might be using, there's different ways of detecting value changes, but it would look something like this:

```
this.NotifyPropertyChanged += (o, e) => {
  if (e.PropertyName == "Status")
  {
    if (this.Status == "Active") EndDate = null;  //nullable DateTime?
    else if (this.Status == "Inactive") EndDate = DateTime.Now;
  }
};
```

In MVVM, your view only does things related to displaying things to the user.  Logic belongs in the view model.  Note that this code relates to the line item object being displayed in the grid, not your outer view model.

Hopefully this helps you get started.

Comment: how can i implement this using Catel

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Catel

Answer (score 0):

This should help....

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public string Status{get;
        set{
            ...
            RaisePropertyChange("EndDate");
        }
    }

    public string EndDate{
        get{
            return Status=="Active" ? "Completed On" + DateTime.Now : "";
        }
    }
}
```